What is $E[X+Y | X-Y < a] \cdot P(X-Y < a)$ for random variables $X$ and $Y$?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent normal random variables, each with known mean and variance. How can I compute?
$$E[X+Y | X-Y < a] P(X-Y < a)$$
My attempt:
By the linearity of expectation, we can break this down:
$$E[X+Y | X-Y < a] P(X-Y < a)$$
$$E[X | X-Y < a] P(X-Y < a) + E[Y | X-Y < a] P(X-Y < a)$$
Consider just the first term (the second is very similar):
$$E[X | X-Y < a] P(X-Y < a)$$
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{x-a}^\infty \frac{\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}\right)}{\sigma_X} \frac{\phi\left(\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)}{\sigma_Y} x \; dx$$
where $\phi$ is the PDF of the standard normal distribution.
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}\right)}{\sigma_X} x \int_{x-a}^\infty \frac{\phi\left(\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right)}{\sigma_Y} dx$$
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}\right)}{\sigma_X} x \left( 1 - \Phi \left( \frac{x - a - \mu_Y}{\sigma_Y} \right) \right) dx$$
where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.
$$ = \mu_X - \int_{-\infty}^\infty x \frac{\phi\left(\frac{x-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}\right)}{\sigma_X} \Phi \left( \frac{x - a - \mu_Y}{\sigma_Y} \right) dx$$
Now I'm stuck :(

Hint: what's the joint distribution of $(X+Y, X-Y)$?

Denote $X=a_1+b_1Z_1$ and $Y=a_2+b_2Z_2$ where $Z_i$ are $N(0,1)$ and independent. Let $c=\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2}$, $b_1=c \cos \theta $, $b_2=c \sin \theta$. Consider also $Z_3=Z_1\cos \theta +Z_2 \sin \theta$ and $Z_4=Z_1\cos \theta -Z_2 \sin \theta.$ They are $N(0,1)$ but not independent with correlation coefficient $r=\cos^2 \theta-\sin ^2 \theta=\cos 2 \theta.$ For this reason we introduce $Z_5$ by $Z_3=Z_4 \cos 2\theta+Z_5 \sin 2\theta$ which is $N(0,1)$ and independent of $Z_4.$  Now denoting $A=(a_2-a_1+a)/c$
$$E(X+Y|X-Y<a)=a_1+a_2+c\cos 2\theta E(Z_4| Z_4<A)+c\sin 2\theta E(Z_5| Z_4<A)$$ Note that $E(Z_5| Z_4<A)=0$ since $Z_4$ and $Z_5$ are independent. Now we observe
$$\Pr(X-Y<a)=\Pr(Z_4<A)=\phi(A)$$ Finally the desired quantity is
$$(a_1+a_2)\phi (A)+c\cos 2\theta \int_{-\infty}^A ze^{-z^2/2}dz/\sqrt{2\pi}$$
where the last integral is easily computable, with a discussion on the sign of $A.$
